# Unable to mix ecto.create. Multiple errors

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, elixir-mix

When trying to run `mix ecto.create` I got the following errors:

1. `.Repo couldn't be created: tcp connect: connection refused - :econnrefused`
2. `.Repo couldn't be created: FATAL (invalid_authorization_specification): role "postgres" does not exist`
3. `.Repo couldn't be created: FATAL (invalid_authorization_specification): role "postgres" is not permitted to log in`

What are the conditions that Postgres must meet in order to properly setup Phoenix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to run `mix ecto.create` you need a series of conditions:

1. Postgres must be up and running.
2. Postgres must have a user `postgres` with the password `postgres`.
3. The `postgres` user must have permissions to both **LOGIN** and **CREATEDB**.

I, for instance, had Postgres running locally but was missing the `postgres` user.

So within [PSQL](http://postgresguide.com/utilities/psql.html) I had to use the following command:

```
# CREATE ROLE postgres LOGIN CREATEDB PASSWORD 'postgres';
```

And then it worked.

Kudos to [Wendy Smoak](http://wiki.wsmoak.net/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?action=browse&diff=1&id=PhoenixPostgres).

Answer (score 0):

1. start your postgres: (assuming you are using a mac)

   pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start

You can then change in cofig/dev.exs the database config at the bottom to use your account with role able to create a db.

Comment: Nice! An alternative way :) Although the error message in the question mentions the postgres role specifically